# web scraping help needed

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if someone could help me put together some code for 
    https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSCO.l?p=TSCO.L

I currently use this code to scrape the current price

```
currentPriceData = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
```

This works fine but I occasionally get an error not really sure why as the links are all correct. but I would like to try to get the price again

so something like

```
try: 
    currentPriceData = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
except Exception:
    currentPriceData = soup.find('span', {'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})[0].text
```

The problem is that I can't get it to scrape the number using this method any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want yahoo finance data there is an api, check this https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Comment: I find it too slow compared to scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT (16.03.2023): Updated to working version**

To get current price you can use next example (don't forget to set `User-Agent` HTTP header):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ticker = 'TSCO.L'
url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}?p={ticker}'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')

current = soup.select_one(f'fin-streamer[data-field="regularMarketPrice"][data-symbol="{ticker}"]')
print(current['value'])
```

Prints:

```
263.2
```

---

Previous version of this answer was parsing for JSON data embedded in the site's HTML which is no longer valid.

Comment: cheers Ill have a look. Is there a obvious way to tell if a website is using json?

Comment: @JPWilson Every website is different. In this particular case I found the data in HTML source of the website, but inside `<script>` tag. Other websites might download the data dynamically via Ajax.

Comment: @JPWilson I added some comentaries to the answer.

Comment: I think Ive worked a fair bit of it out I guess I have four questions if you wouldnt mind answering 1. does root.app.main mean we are always using json?
2. data =  ({.*?});\n',  what does this part of the code mean exactly I checked the source and I dont get why you put this and I googled it and didnt find anything 
3. group(1)) how do you know which group to do? 
4. Did you have prior experience with yahoo or did you do that on the fly? I understand what you are doing with the keys but It would take me ages to get all the keys correctly is there a fast way?

Comment: @JPWilson 1.) `root.app.main` is specific only for this site (finance.yahoo.com). I used Json module, because it sometimes can decode javascript variables 2.) `({.*?});\n` - this is regexp. I want only extract this specific string from HTML page 3.) `.group(1)` is part of `re.search` - it means I want to extract first group from the regex. 4.) I do it on the fly, every site is different, so you must know how the web operates (HTTP, HTML, Javascript etc...)